# Ctrl and Shift keys are sticky

Tags: keyboard, tablet

I think Ubuntu recognized my laptop (Asus U32U) as a tablet and after the installation I had huge on-screen keyboard. Deleted by unistalling via Synaptic anything related with virtual keyboard. Now I have a bug like when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it remains pressed until I press/click something else (like in smartphones and tablets). Not sure about <kbd>Alt</kbd>. 
How to deal with it?
inb4 thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have "Sticky Keys" off?